# Dynamics CRM permission import do not have access

Tags: import, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a user performing a data import into Dynamics CRM. The partial error on the import says the user does not have enough privileges to access the Dynamics CRM Object for 2 lookup columns. One of them the user imported. The importer can see both the lookup list values.  Can someone explain the proper permissions required for the user performing the data import?

Comment: Post the actual error message, some screenshots may help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned they can see, ie `Read` privilege. Check `Write` privilege as well.

Most importantly, Lookup attribute import needs `AppendTo` & `Append` privileges in respective entities.

When you are importing EntityA having EntityB lookup, importing User should have a security role with `AppendTo` in EntityA & `Append` in EntityB privileges + appropriate (user/BU level) access levels

Verify the `AppendTo` & `Append` privileges of those entities.

I assume you already verified [these mentioned privileges](https://www.powerobjects.com/2015/08/18/data-import-privileges/).

**Update**:

Seems like custom Power user role (probably created from scratch) is throwing problems. Always start with cloning OOB security roles like salesperson & fill out the needed privileges. This helps to carry the hidden privileges.

Avoid giving highest privilege like Sys.Admin which will give users more than what needed, for ex. Bulk delete button will appear in Delete ribbon flyout & once my user configured Bulk delete job assuming record deletion action.

Atleast remove it once the import job is done.

Comment: I tried all of this.  No love.  I believe in order to perform an import, the user must be a system admin.  Not desirable but this appears to be required.

Comment: Are you trying with a security role which is created from scratch..? There may be some hidden privileges, better clone from an existing role like salesperson & remove the unwanted privileges.. then assign that role to users.  @Chives

Comment: Good point.  I actually modified the Power User role.  Knew I shouldn't do that but it's in a test VM I have

Comment: probably you have to check how that Power user role is created, clone a system role & give all that Power role privilege into that one to test..

Comment: I gave the user system admin system rights and all is well.  I can't waste any more time working on this.  Giving someone read rights on the lookup should be sufficient.  (Works for SQL, SharePoint, etc...).

Comment: @Chives Worth to mention, giving higher privilege will lead to confusion & errand activities. :)  feel free to upvote if it helped you.

Comment: Which was why I opened this discussion.  I don't like to give out too much permission.  Unfortunately it appears to be required to run imports.  Thanks for the insight.